# Contact Angle acid-base approach negative square root

Tags: measurements, surface-tension

I've collected Contact Angles for 3 different liquids (ethylene glycol, glycerol, and water) on a substrate. My aim is to use the acid-base approach (eq. below) to obtain the dispersion, acid, and base interfacial energy components of the substrate. I got the values for the liquids out of books. 

$
\gamma_{lv} (1 + \cos( \theta_y)) \cdot 0.5 = \sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^d \cdot \gamma_{lv}^d } + \sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^{acid} \cdot \gamma_{lv}^{base}} + \sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^{base} \cdot \gamma_{lv}^{acid}} 
$

My idea was basically to take the 3 equations and solve them by a linear system. The square roots of the solid-vapor parameters were the unknown variables. One of the results is negative ($\sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^{acid}} \approx -5$). In itself, the physical quantity $\gamma_{sv}$ is positive through squaring. But in the papers I read, if the values were negative for the square root, they were close to zero. Most of them weren't negative anyway.
It's pretty likely that something went wrong during the measurement. Is a negative result for $\sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^{acid}}$ supporting this? Or have you seen other results where the square root of one component was negative? I know the choice of liquid is improvable (like with diiodomethane or methylene iodide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acid-base approach was criticized for that possible outcome. However, according to Good and Oss, negative surface energy components are physically allowable as long as the total surface energy is positive. The formula for the total surface energy is 
$\gamma_{sv} = \gamma_{sv}^{LW} + \gamma_{sv}^{AB} = \gamma_{sv}^{LW} + 2\sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^+} \sqrt{\gamma_{sv}^-}$

Reasons for the anomalous could be:

- Experimental Error
- spreading pressure which was neglected in the acid-base approach
- the choice of the 3 liquids. Due to an ill-conditioned matrix, relatively small changes in the "input" values lead to big changes in the solution. A set of recommended liquids is methylene iodide, water and Formamide/ Ethylene Glycol/ Glycerol.

Despite that, there are more general critiques. The values for the liquid components used are not based on physical properties. It was discussed whether water should have the same value for the lewis acid and lewis base.
 Further critique is due to its inadequate mathematical presentation, repoted by [Greiveldinger and Shanahan](https://doi.org/10.1006/jcis.1999.6259)

References:
[Contact angle measurements and interpretation](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0001-8686(98)00087-6) Chapter 3.1.3. by Kwok and Neumann 
[The Modern Theory of Contact Angles and the Hydrogen Bond Components of Surface Energies](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-1176-6_1) by Good and Oss